# mocha js assertion hangs while using promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, bdd, assert

```
"use strict";
let assert = require("assert");

describe("Promise test", function() {
  it('should pass', function(done) {
    var a = {};
    var b = {};
    a.key = 124;
    b.key = 567;
    let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
        }, 100)
    });

    p.then(function success() {

        console.log("success---->", a, b);
        assert.deepEqual(a, b, "response doesnot match");
        done();
    }, function error() {

        console.log("error---->", a, b);
        assert.deepEqual(a, b, "response doesnot match");
        done();
    });
 });
});
```

Output:
[image: output result]

I am using node v5.6.0.
The test seems to hang for assert when values don't match.

I tried to check if it's issue with assert.deepEqual using setTimeout but it works fine.

But it fails while using Promise and hangs if the values don't match.

Comment: You should tell us the output of this, when reading it I was wondering what is your promise library, the output would confirm that some of the `console.log` is called.

Comment: sure. I have added the output and file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that error, because your test is never finished. This assertion: `assert.deepEqual(a, b, "response doesnot match");` throws an error, and so as you haven't catch block, `done` callback is never called.

You should add `catch` block in the end of promise chain:

```
...
p.then(function success() {
    console.log("success---->", a, b);
    assert.deepEqual(a, b, "response doesnot match");
    done();
}, function error() {
    console.log("error---->", a, b);
    assert.deepEqual(a, b, "response doesnot match");
    done();
})
.catch(done); // <= it will be called if some of the asserts are failed
```

Comment: Awesome it worked. I was under impression that mocha will take care of errors.

Comment: Mocha cares only about running your tests in isolated scope. If your code doesn't call `done` callback, mocha informs you about that.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a Promise, I suggest to simply return it at the end of the `it`. Once the Promise is settled (fulfilled or rejected), Mocha will consider the test done and it will consume the Promise. In case of a rejected Promise, it will use its value as the thrown Error.

NB: do not declare a `done` argument if you are returning a Promise.